# Forcing a webview to load a website like chrome

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a website in my app , this is my code:

```
 wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebSettings settings = wb.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wb.loadUrl(bl.getString("url"));
```

i want to load this website :

```
https://webapp.irimo.ir/
```

the problem is , it's showing in chrome but it's not displaying anything in my website .

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because of SSL error.
You can use `onReceivedSslError` method to ignore Ssl error.

```
   @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);

        // this will ignore the Ssl error and will go forward to your site
        handler.proceed();
    }
```

For more information you can look [here](https://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/10/28/android-webview-load-url-ignoring-ssl/#.Xmihh5MzbBI)

Comment: thanks for your reply , I tried it but it doesn't work